# Hide component on button click in React using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, jsx

In a function, I have a button that displays a component on click. How do I hide this component when clicking on that button again (which would work like a toggle)?

```
<Link to="/">
    <div className="navigation">
        <button
            className="about-button"
        >
            About
        </button>
    </div>
</Link>
```

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
        <HomePage />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doing this a bit different then how you normally would approach this. Let me write a quick component from scratch to show you the idea...

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default const ExampleComponent = () => {
   const [showElem, setShowElem] = useState(true)

   return (
     <div>
    { showElem && <h1>Hello</h1> }
    <Button onClick={() => { 
       setShowElem(!showElem) 
    }} />
    </div>
   )
}
```

...You'll have to excuse the formatting I typed this up right here.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now that toggling is not recommended with React Routing.